# Listview of item of StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter

Once the StatefulWidget dispose, (item out of screen) how to retrieve the state of the StatefulWidget?

I'm actually set a animatedlist but I think it's the same probleme. May be update the list might solved the probleme. But how?

I just want the same state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want the `State` that needs to be preserved to use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`.

Here's an example:

```dart
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FooState createState() {
    super.build(context);
    return new FooState();
  }
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Such `Foo` widget will preserve its state even if it leaves the screen inside a `ListView`